# How can you output Cyrillic (Russian) characters to console in Visual Studio C++?

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to print out cyrillic characters in my output in one of my programs. However, they are coming out as all question marks when the program runs. Why would this be and how would I be able to fix it?
I will leave my code below:

```
 while (languageInput != 1 && languageInput != 2) // if user enters invalid input
{
    cout<< u8"Enter 1 for Russian(Русский) or 2 for English: ";
    cin >> languageInput;
    cout << endl; 
}
if (languageInput == 1) // русский
{
    cout << u8"Как вас зовут? ";
    cin >> name; //ввод имени
    cout << endl;
    cout << u8"Привет " << name << u8" и добро пожаловать в класс CS113!" << endl; //выпуск
}
```

Comment: The console window doesn't use UTF-8 unless you set it as the code page.

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: You might start by looking at https://stackoverflow.com/q/57131654/5987

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert this at the beginning of main function:

setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Great! But might be do you know how make it working with dll which doesn't contain main function?